# iphone dateFromString giving warning message 'NSDate' may not respond to '+ variable name'

Tags: iphone, string, warnings, nsdate

```
warning: 'NSDate' may not respond to '+currDate'
```

Above is a warning message when I compile the following code:

```
-(IBAction)getDate:(id)sender   {
currDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[ dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    strCurrDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate currDate]];
displayDate.text = strCurrDate;
[dateFormatter release];
```

}
I'm just trying to get the current date and display it in a label called `displayDate`.
Using the debugger I can see that the date is never converted to a string and stored into `strCurrDate`.

The warning message is on the line where I try to use `stringFromDate`

Can anyone see why this isn't working properly? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I also currDate is my header file:

```
 NSDate         *currDate;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `currDate` is not a class method of `NSDate` instead it is a property of your class. So this line:

```
strCurrDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate currDate]];
```

should be:

```
strCurrDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];
```

Comment: wow... just wow. i've been trying to figure that out for hours!